# Return a response from routes.yaml without a controller

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to return `OK` whenever I go to `/health` and did it like this which works great:

HealthController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class HealthController
{
    public function ok() {
        return new Response('OK');
    }
}
```

routes.yaml

```
health:
  path: /health
  controller: App\Controller\HealthController::ok
```

But is there a way to do the exact same thing without having to create a controller?

Maybe something like the following:

```
health:
  path: /health
  return: 'OK'
```

Comment: if you will be using only router component not the whole symfony then yes otherwise no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 workarounds I can think of to achieve this. When you use Twig you can use the TemplateController::templateAction to render a static template. See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/render_without_controller.html

You could write a `HealthCheckEventListener` that subscribes to the `kernel.request` event and then does what you want when the request contains the path. You can then reuse it for other projects.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is you would have a route without *any* controller and this is (as far as I know) not possible in Symfony. In fact I think in every MVC-framework you would need a controller to control the output, because that is one of the main principles of the MVC-framework.